# Virtualenv: Fatal Python error: PyImport_GetModuleDict: no module dictionary

Tags: windows, python-2.7

This happened to a script that was executing for a while before it failed. The script has been deployed for over 6 months and this message has never been observed before.

We are using Python 2.7 on Windows in a virtualenv.

Any ideas what causes it, or any possible workarounds?

Comment: can you add the script or some code?

Comment: A stack trace from the `Py_FatalError` call would help to determine why `interp->modules` is `NULL` at the time.

Comment: The only output observed is:  Fatal Python error: PyImport_GetModuleDict: no module dictionary!  
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.  
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: The full script is located here: [link](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/pytests/powertest.py)